# Spring JMS listener for AWS SQS queue configuration with concurrency

Tags: java, spring, jms, amazon-sqs

I am trying to figure out how to configure jms listener to listen AWS queue and process messages in many threads (~100 simultaneously).

Below is my configuration.

```
@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class JmsConfig {

    @Bean
    public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory(AmazonSQS amazonSQS) {
        ProviderConfiguration providerConfiguration = new ProviderConfiguration().withNumberOfMessagesToPrefetch(0);
        SQSConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new SQSConnectionFactory(providerConfiguration, amazonSQS);
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        factory.setDestinationResolver(new DynamicDestinationResolver());
        factory.setConcurrency("30-100");
        factory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        factory.setCacheLevel(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.CACHE_CONNECTION);
        factory.setErrorHandler(t -> {
        });
        return factory;
    }

}
```

With this confuguration I keep receiving the following error:

> SQSMessageConsumer - Can't terminate executor service ConsumerPrefetch
>   after 30 seconds, some running threads will be shutdown immediately

Also, publishing messages into **AmazonSQS** instance takes 20 seconds.

I tried different combinations of **NumberOfMessagesToPrefetch** and **CacheLevel** but nothing works properly.

E.g. **CacheLevel = CACHE_CONSUMER** works with no errors but processes 1 message at a time.

Please help me to configure this.
Thanks!

Libraries:

- aws-java-sdk:1.11.41
- spring-jms:5.1.7
- amazon-sqs-java-messaging-lib:1.0.6

Comment: Were you able to figure out?

Comment: @MaverickRiz, no, I am using manual concurrency:

Answer (score 0):

@[Boris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/368532/boris)
I was able to resolve this issue the following way. I do not set Cache Level. The provider configuration is still disabling prefetching

`ProviderConfiguration providerConfiguration = new ProviderConfiguration().withNumberOfMessagesToPrefetch(0);`

Additionally, I use `DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory` and then set the following values, in addition to other values not shown:

---

### DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory

`factory.setConcurrency("5-10"); //This will depend on your use case
factory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE); //Used to in-flight erroneous messages
factory.setTaskExecutor(threadPoolTaskExecutor()); //Uses threadpooltask executor, see below
factory.setMaxMessagesPerTask(10); //Not required, but to reduce thread-switching. This will depend on your use case`

---

Please read [ThreadPool Executor](http://www.bigsoft.co.uk/blog/2009/11/27/rules-of-a-threadpoolexecutor-pool-size) before using ThreadPool Executor, written almost 12 years ago but still valid. I do not set concurrency on the @JmsListener level because it causes additional complexity [JmsListener Concurrency](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/20885)